# Probability distribution morphing from Gaussian to heavy tail

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I require a probability distribution which morphs from a something similar to a Gaussian (image 1) to something with a heavy tail on one side (image 2) based on some parameter. Can someone give me a hint what could be suitable?

[image]

[image]

There is a cut-off (here 64), and bigger values just get probability 0. The plots are not normalized, so don't bother about that.

Comment: A find this question quite unclear.  No probability distribution changes from one distribution to another; it simply is one distribution.  The density in your first picture does not look at all Gaussian: it's conspicuously asymmetric.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I look for a family of distributions where there is one parameter which adapts the shape. Like the beta distribution for example.

Comment: Did you intend the mode to be in the same place in both distributions?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: That would be good.

Comment: It's possible that a Frechet or maybe Weibull distribution could do what you want.  These are part of the "extreme value" family.  Gumbel distributions, mentioned in another comment, are part of the family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always build you own by using a weighted sum of two distributions. $f=a f_1 + (1-a)f_2$ Careful on the choice of $f_2$, many of the likely candidates (e.g. $\chi^2$) are only defined for $x>0$. The truncation you will have to build in manually, but remember to renormalize afterwards.

Comment: Could you give me some suggestions for f_2?

Comment: Gumbel?  This link is to a pdf that lists lots of distributions http://www.causascientia.org/math_stat/Dists/Compendium.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You could try a mixture of two distributions, $Y(\beta)=(1-\beta)Z + \beta \cdot X$ where $Z$ is a normal distribution and $X$ some contaminating distribution (say a skewed heavy-tailed distribution). Now vary $\beta$ between $0$ and $1$ to get your ``morphing''.

Examples for $X$ could be [stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). The big disadvantage is that the densities are not known explicitly for most cases. One nice exception is the [Lévy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution). It has parameters which you can adjust to drive for example the mode.